# Quick add vertices when creating feature (QGIS 3.2)

Tags: qgis, snapping, digitizing, vertices

I am creating a new feature (polygon) in QGIS 3.2.2 and would like to easily add the vertices as I delineate a boundary.  Currently, I can do this one by one as the cursor snaps to the vertex of the features in the layer I am referencing.  But there are many vertices and (ideally) I would like to quickly go over the vertices and if they are within snapping distance they are automatically added to the new feature.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply enable Automatic Tracing by clicking this icon:[image]

Check out Automatic Tracing in the user manual [here](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#automatic-tracing).